# Add attribute to xml with XML::Simple

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I am trying to add an attribute to existing XML, using XML::Simple.

```
<arbre>
  <branche name="courbe" >
    <description>
      <![CDATA[une belle branche]]>
    </description>
    <feuilles>
      <fleur color="blue" order="1" />
      <fleur color="white" order="2" />
      <fleur color="yellow" order="3" />
    </feuilles>
  </branche>
  <branche name="droite" >
    <description>
      <![CDATA[une branche commune]]>
    </description>
    <feuilles>
      <fleur color="purple" order="1" />
      <fleur color="green" order="2" />
    </feuilles>
  </branche>
</arbre>
```

That I am trying to transform into :

```
<arbre>
  <branche name="courbe" type="conifere">
    <description>
      <![CDATA[une belle branche]]>
    </description>
    <feuilles>
      <fleur color="blue" order="1" />
      <fleur color="white" order="2" />
      <fleur color="yellow" order="3" />
    </feuilles>
  </branche>
  <branche name="droite" type="resineux">
    <description>
      <![CDATA[une branche commune]]>
    </description>
    <feuilles>
      <fleur color="purple" order="1" />
      <fleur color="green" order="2" />
    </feuilles>
  </branche>
</arbre>
```

Notice the type attribute in branche tag.
So far I have the following :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w

use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $funclist = XML::Simple->new();
my $arbres   = $funclist->XMLin("test.xml");

print Dumper($arbres);
exit 0;
```

From what I understand from the documentation $arbres is a hash in which I have to insert in each branche key the type attribute key and value.
Exept that I have no clue at where and how ($arbres{something} = "conifere" ?).
Thanks

Comment: XML::Simple is usually far from simple to use, and it's own documentation says *"The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended. The major problems with this module are the large number of options and the arbitrary ways in which these options interact - often with unexpected results."*

Comment: [Why is XML::Simple "discouraged"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use XML::Simple qw();

my %branche_map = (
    courbe => 'conifere',
    droite => 'resineux',
);
my $xs = XML::Simple->new(StrictMode => 1, ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => undef, RootName => 'arbre');
my $arbres = $xs->XMLin('test.xml');

for my $branche (@{ $arbres->{branche} }) {
    $branche->{type} = $branche_map{ $branche->{name} };
}
print $xs->XMLout($arbres)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML)

```
open test.xml ;
for //branche[@name='courbe'] set @type 'conifere' ;
for //branche[@name='droite'] set @type 'resineux' ;
save :b ;
```